# Wacom + Maya = Viewport problem

Tags: wacom, xsetwacom

I need your help.

I just bought my first Wacom product ever, and sadly it's  not working with the only program I make a living with = Autodesk Maya.
Maya is made by Autodesk, and is the industry-standard for film and CGI,  used by Disney and basically everyone in the CG deparment. I've even  made a project for their VP in the past.

First, let me start by saying I bought 3 tablets from 3 different brands to test this, and the results are:

- XP-Pen (closed source driver) = Maya works fine;
- Huion (closed source driver) = Maya works fine;
- Huion (linuxwacom open-source driver + Digimend Kernel drivers) = Maya doesn't work;
- Wacom (linuxwacom open-source driver) = Maya doesn't work;

I have arthritis and I found that I can't work with  Mouse+Keyboard, but using a graphics tablet makes me fully capable of  working and I have no pain at all.
I've been using a Huion tablet for some years and it works fine under  Linux with Maya (H320M). I then bought an XP-Pen tablet and it also  works fine (Deco 01 v2).
Recently I've been curious about Wacom and decided to buy  an Intuos Pro S. The size was perfect for my use, but as you'll see in  the following video, some of the most important Maya functions don't  work.

You can see a video of the problem here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s35HdWs3-Hs

To try this, you can download a trial version of Maya here: https://www.autodesk.com/products/maya/free-trial
I'm currently running:
Debian 12.1;
KDE 5.27.5;
libwacom-common 2.6.0-1;
NVIDIA RTX 3060 12 GB;
128 GB Corsair Vengeance PRO DDR4;
Ryzen 7 5800X;

I wonder if anyone has any idea of how I could fix this, otherwise I'll have to return this tablet and use Huion and their proprietary driver.
Cheers